# How do I pass a view object to be rendered in a child view?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to build a reusable popup view with it's own template and CSS. In this reusable view, I want to be able to display child views with the content that the parent view wants to put in the popup.

The handlebars template for the popup looks like this:

```
<div class='popup'>
    <a class='open' href='#' {{action toggleVisible}}>
        {{view button}}
    </a>

    <div class='collapse'>
        <div class='box'>
            <div class='arrow'></div>
            <div class='arrow-border'></div>

            {{view content}}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this context, `button` and `content` should be Ember views that get rendered inside this popup and those views will be different depending on what parent view is creating and displaying the popup.

The popup View object looks like this:

```
var popup = Ember.View.extend({
    button: null,
    content: null,
    templateName: 'popbox',
    visible: false,
    toggleVisible: function() {
        var visible = this.get('visible');
        this.set('visible', !visible);
        if (visible) {
            this.$().find('.box').fadeOut(250);
        } else {
            var pop = this.$().find('.popbox');
            var box = this.$().find('.box');
                box.css({
                    'display': 'block',
                    'top': 10,
                    'left': ((pop.parent().width()/2) -box.width()/2 )
                    });
            }
        }
    }
}));
```

I'm not sure how to pass the templates to be rendered in the popup from the parent view. Right now I'm trying to do something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
var sendto = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'sendto',
    popupView: popup.extend({
        button: Ember.View.extend({
            template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{model.selectedRecipients.length}} {{model.peopleOrPersonText}}')}),
        content: Ember.View.extend({template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('Test content')})
    })
}));
```

What would be the correct way to pass views to the popup view?

NOTE: This appears to work but it generates a DEPRECATED error message:

```
Something you did caused a view to re-render after it rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM.
```

**UPDATE:** It turns out my issue was due to something else entirely (was accidently including Ember.js twice). The code above actually seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Ember.ContainerView, and have the internal views each be their own view class with their own template. Then, you can just set the childViews array on the containing view to contain an instance of whatever view you want to display.